# JSON array to Table structure formatting while sending email via Mule 4

Tags: html, json, smtp, dataweave, mule4

I have a requirement to send the error report as a tabular format, which needs to be sent as a email body.
I am constructing error report as a JSON array and I would need to do the HTML transformation to structure that as table format.

Below is the JSON array and the expected result as email body.

```
[ { "templateID": "72", "houseNumber": "SR0000V-test", "dataMigrationSourceId": 2102866, "errorDescription": "Process aborted:CatalogItem not found in Target system!" }, { "templateID": "", "houseNumber": "SR0000V-test", "dataMigrationSourceId": 2102866, "errorDescription": "Process aborted: TemplateID is not present!" } ]
```

Expected Email Body:
[image]

If not exactly same format, would need the result something similar to the table structure or more readable format.
Can some one please help me construct this format in Mule 4

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Html Table (Payload)**

You can customize your css inside @(). I just kept a sample which can be useful to you

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
---
{
    table @(style: "width: 50%; border: 1px solid grey; font-family: Monospace" ): {
        tr @(bgcolor: "#6c7ae0",style: "color: white !important; font-size:14px; "): {
            th @() : "templateId",
            th @() : "houseNumber",
            th @() : "dataMigrationSourceId",
            th @() : "errorDescription"
        },
        (payload map (item, index) -> {
            tr @(align:"center", style: "color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%"): {
                td @(): item.templateID,
                td @(): item.houseNumber,
                td @(): item.dataMigrationSourceId,
                td @(): item.errorDescription
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Parser Template**

I further used **Parser template** Connector to write the html content because the above table we will be sending as html table embedded in mail.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello XYZ,</p>
    <p>Please find the error report for today's run. </p>
    <br />
  #[payload]
<br /><br />
<p>This is an automated mail, please do not reply.</p>
<br />
<p>Thanks and Regards,</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here payload denotes the html table we created above.

Finally in the mail (Send) connector you can refer this html table as **payload** in the Content of Body.

**Note** - Make sure you change the ContentType to **text/html** in the Body of mail Send connector

Comment: Hi Karthik, Thanks a lot for the quick response, it is working exactly as expected.