# need to display json array output in tabular form in html for a mule application

Tags: javascript, html, json, mule, dataweave

Given I have json output as:

```
[
  {
    "appName": "abc-supportcase-proc-api",
    "depedencies": [
      {
        "connector": "abc-supportcase-proc-api",
        "version": "1.0.13"
      },
      {
        "connector": "mule-file-connector",
        "version": "1.3.3"
      },
      {
        "connector": "mule-objectstore-connector",
        "version": "1.1.6"
      },
      {
        "connector": "mule-validation-module",
        "version": "1.4.0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "appName": "def-classification-sap-sys-api",
    "depedencies": [
      {
        "connector": "mule-sap-connector",
        "version": "5.1.1"
      },
      {
        "connector": "def-classification-sap-sys-api",
        "version": "1.0.5"
      },
      {
        "connector": "com.sap.conn.idoc.sapidoc3",
        "version": "3.0.13"
      },
      {
        "connector": "com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3",
        "version": "3.0.19"
      },
      {
        "connector": "libsapjco3",
        "version": "3.0.19"
      }
    ]
  }
...
...
]
```

I need to display this in a tabular format like first column should be appName and other columns will be the connector values(headers) and versions will be the corresponding value of version. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you explain how you want this to be in a tabular format since the connectors are having different values under different headers.

Comment: appName                            |abc-supportcase-proc-api            | mule-file-connector  |   
abc-supportcase-proc-api  |1.0.13                                            | 1.0.13

Comment: not able to post in tabular format here .... but  headers will be appName and all connector names and data in rows should be name of app with versions if these connectors

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully clear on you expectation. My solution uses the method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66632625/721855) to generate HTML from the Mule application. I first convert the data to a more usable format and extract column names, then generate dynamically the output. If you prefer to generate the table in JavaScript you may keep the logic to get the data in more usable way from variables tableData (optionally connectorNames too) to set the output of the Mule application. It doesn't look to be difficult to translate the table generation part in JavaScript.

```js
%dw 2.0
import indexOf from dw::core::Arrays
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
var tableData=payload flatMap ((item, index) -> item.depedencies 
        map ((dependency, depIndex) -> 
            { 
                appName: item.appName,
                connectorName: dependency.connector,
                connectorVersion: dependency.version
            }
        )
) 
var connectorNames=tableData reduce ((item, accumulator=[]) ->  accumulator ++ [item.connectorName] )
---
{
    table @(style: "width: 50%; border: 1px solid grey; font-family: Monospace" ): {
        tr @(bgcolor: "#6c7ae0",style: "color: white !important; font-size:14px; "): 
        { th @(): "appName" } ++ (connectorNames reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ {th @(): item}) )
        ,
        (tableData map (item, index) -> {
            tr @(align:"center", style: "color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%"): {
                td @(): item["appName"],
                (connectorNames map td @(): if ((connectorNames indexOf(item.connectorName)) == $$) item.connectorVersion else "")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<table style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid grey; font-family: Monospace">
  <tr bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; font-size:14px; ">
    <th>appName</th>
    <th>abc-supportcase-proc-api</th>
    <th>mule-file-connector</th>
    <th>mule-objectstore-connector</th>
    <th>mule-validation-module</th>
    <th>mule-sap-connector</th>
    <th>def-classification-sap-sys-api</th>
    <th>com.sap.conn.idoc.sapidoc3</th>
    <th>com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3</th>
    <th>libsapjco3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>abc-supportcase-proc-api</td>
    <td>1.0.13</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>abc-supportcase-proc-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td>1.3.3</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>abc-supportcase-proc-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>1.1.6</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>abc-supportcase-proc-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>1.4.0</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>def-classification-sap-sys-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>5.1.1</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>def-classification-sap-sys-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>1.0.5</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>def-classification-sap-sys-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>3.0.13</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>def-classification-sap-sys-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>3.0.19</td>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td>def-classification-sap-sys-api</td>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td>3.0.19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```