# Json to HTML in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: html, json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to convert a json array to html (in a tabular format) using dataweave 2.0 in MuleSoft. My input payload is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Product ID": "4d5c0b68",
    "Product Number": "be56",
    "Product Name": "Product A",
    "Product Priority": "High Risk",
    "Product Attachments": 2,
    "Combo?": "No"
  }
]
```

The html output that I need is below:

```
<table style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; font-family: Monospace">
  <tr bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product ID</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid blue; font-size:14px; ">Product Number</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Priority</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Attachments</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Combo?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; border: 1px solid black; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">4d5c0b68</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">be56</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product A</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">High Risk</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">2</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The json data currently given is for only 1 row and I will have to map the whole array in the html. Can this be achieved using dataweave 2.0?

This is what I have currently.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
var tableData = payload map ((item, index) -> 
{
    "Product ID" : item.ProductID,
    "Product Number": item.ProductNumber,
    "Product Name": item.ProductName,
    "Product Priority": item.ProductPriority,
    "Product Attachments": item.ProductAttachments as Number,
    "Combo?" : if (item.Combo == "false") "No" else "Yes"
})
var headerRow = [
    {
        "header": "Product ID",
        "style": "color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;"
    },
    {
        "header": "Product Number",
        "style": "color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;"
    },
    {
        "header": "Product Name",
        "style": "color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;"
    },
    {
        "header": "Product Priority",
        "style": "color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;"
    },
    {
        "header": "Product Attachments",
        "style": "color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;"
    },
    {
        "header": "Combo?",
        "style": "color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;"
    }
]
---
<table style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; font-family: Monospace">
  <tr bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">Case #</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid blue; font-size: 14px;">Interaction #</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">Product Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">PQC Priority</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">No. of PQC Attachments</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">Combo?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size: 12px; border: 1px solid black; font-weight: 500; width: 10%">
    <td style="color: black !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">{(tableData[0]."Product ID")}</td>
    <td style="color: black !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">{(tableData[0]."Product Number")}</td>
    <td style="color: black !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">{(tableData[0]."Product Name")}</td>
    <td style="color: black !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">{(tableData[0]."Product Priority")}</td>
    <td style="color: black !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">{(tableData[0]."Product Attachments")}</td>
    <td style="color: black !important; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px;">{(tableData[0]."Combo?")}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you share your dataweave?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question with the dataweave that I have tried already. It's incorrect and I am trying to fix the errors. Kindly check

Comment: Not exactly the same. But this may help you to get some idea. Does this answer your question? [JSON array to Table structure formatting while sending email via Mule 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66632026/json-array-to-table-structure-formatting-while-sending-email-via-mule-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataWeave does not support HTML as an output type (Check [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.2/dataweave-formats) for supported formats). However, we can use "application/xml" to prepare the HTML content with the necessary tags, and then output the result with the content type set to "text/html" when sending emails or to the target system. I hope this information is helpful.

Input

```
[
  {
    "Product ID": "4d5c0b68",
    "Product Number": "be56",
    "Product Name": "Product A",
    "Product Priority": "High Risk",
    "Product Attachments": 2,
    "Combo?": "No"
  },
  {
    "Product ID": "4d5c0b68",
    "Product Number": "be56",
    "Product Name": "Product A",
    "Product Priority": "High Risk",
    "Product Attachments": 2,
    "Combo?": "No"
  }
]
```

DataWeave Script

```
%dw 2.0
var keys = keysOf(payload[0]) // Headers
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
---
table @(style:"width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; font-family: Monospace"): {
    //Headers Mapping
    tr @(bgcolor:"#6c7ae0", style:"color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; "): {
        (keys map ((item, index) -> {
            th @(bgcolor: "#6c7ae0", style: "color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; "):item
        }))
    },
    //Values Mapping
    (payload map ((item, index) -> {
        tr @(align:"center", style:"color: #666666; font-size:12px; border: 1px solid black; font-weight: 500; width:10%"): {
            (item mapObject {
                td @(style:"color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ", ): $
            })
        }
    }))
}
```

Output

```
<table style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; font-family: Monospace">
  <tr bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product ID</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Number</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Priority</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product Attachments</th>
    <th bgcolor="#6c7ae0" style="color: white !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Combo?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; border: 1px solid black; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">4d5c0b68</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">be56</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product A</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">High Risk</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">2</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color: #666666; font-size:12px; border: 1px solid black; font-weight: 500; width:10%">
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">4d5c0b68</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">be56</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">Product A</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">High Risk</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">2</td>
    <td style="color: black !important;border: 1px solid black; font-size:14px; ">No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers if they already help to solve the question.

Comment: Thanks @jarus, The DW works  as expected for single JSON object in the  input array. However, if there are multiple objects in the input array, then they are merged into the second 'tr' as multiple 'td' elements. Based on my HTML knowledge, this is not expected and every record should be nested under its own 'tr' XML element. Kindly check and see if the answer can be updated to accomodate this.

Comment: Thank you @TheOtherGuy for your feedback. It helped me notice a mistake in the code, which I have now corrected.